# Can't install PHP extension sdo on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, php, software-installation

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 with PHP Version 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.7. I have tried the standard instructions to install sdo: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.installation.php as well as the instructions in the comments on: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58951.

I even tried this unofficial version on Github: https://github.com/CloCkWeRX/sdo.

(I also tried all of the above with a newer PHP version -   5.5.9+dfsg-1+sury.org~quantal+1 from [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/php5))

All methods error out during **make**. I am trying to install this so that I can use an UPS's API for shipping methods. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked out a solution to install sdo on Ubuntu 12.10. First, I downgraded PHP to the 5.3.x series, using this script and instructions from here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-downgrade-php-version-from-5-4-to-5-3-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal.html

Next, I downloaded a patched version of sdo from here: https://pety.homelinux.org/cloudbank_repo/SCA_SDO-1.2.5.tgz

Finally, I patched the code as follows:

Edit sdo.cpp
- remove all "static" modifiers, except "static char rcs_id[]..."

Edit commonj/sdo/SDODataConverter.cpp
- add "#include <stdio.h>"

and then I simply ran the usual commands to compile:

```
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Then I verified that sdo was compiled in by visiting phpinfo.php on my server, and all was working:
[image: sdo section from phpinfo() output]